# Graphic glitches in virt-manager win-xp guest

Tags: windows-xp, qemu, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I'm having graphical issues with my windows XP guest in virt-manager. I haven't done any extensive testing, but at the moment I have only encountered it inside the game 3D Pinball Space Cadet (which may or may not have been the second biggest reason for this virtualization project in the first place). It does not appear when fooling around with simple transparency in paint, or in any of the other included games that I can see (not much transparency going on in solitaire, maybe something is wrong in the corners of the cards?).

It looks to my eyes like it's some sort of faulty alpha transparency. Below is an example of what I am getting and, according to the included helpdocs of 3D Pinball Space Cadet, what it's supposed to look like.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I have not touched any graphics settings since setting it up, using only defaults everywhere (I did follow [this guide](https://mathiashueber.com/virtual-machine-audio-setup-get-pulse-audio-working/) option 2 to make sound work). This is more or less my first foray into virtual machining. I don't know where to start troubleshooting. My host graphics are done by an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 with driver version 470.161.03, on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine. The virtualisation happens through KVM and QEMU, again without having touched any settings after install, as far as I can recall.

I have tried both in my daily driver LeftWM environment and in the Gnome-on-Xorg environment that ships with my Ubuntu. I have also tried and gotten basically the same result on VirtualBox, also with 100% default settings, for whatever that's worth.